# Two users Chat System in node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js

I am planning to build a two users chat system. Where registered members on website can chat to any other user just like facebook but in pop up window not inline.

Now as I will use mysql database to store all chats/messages. I am bit confused in choosing node.js or javasript/ajax only to do this task.

I can build this chat in jquery but bit concerned about performance. Anyone have suggestion?

Comment: JQuery is fine for this. Your question is probably if ajax polling/longpolling is good enough or if you should use websockets, right?

Comment: Yeah, his issues are much more on the server side.  What are you using for a switchboard?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [Private/Public chat](https://github.com/Fabryz/support-chat). Seems a nice implementation using JQuery, Socket.io and Node.js. You'll probably have to modify the template and work out database storage. Btw is there any specific reason you prefer MySQL over NoSQL databases like MongoDB, Redis and the like.

Comment: Hi anand, thanks for answer but the link you provided is not working

Comment: Have corrected the link. Had included .git in the earlier link.

Comment: @almypal Really a good example.. thanks for the link. But i see that it does not work in IE8.

Comment: What is the console logging on the client and server side?

Comment: In IE, the user list does not appear in the right side, as in Firefox and chrome. When i look at the code in **chat.js**, i see that this line of code is not executed.. **users.append('<li><a class="userNick" href="#"....** 
Probably there is a problem in IE with looping json. (**data.users.forEach**). Surprisingly, in the console, it shows the total users correctly. I also tried using the latest jquery, but no use.